# Access to the JSP pages place in subfolders under WebContent folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I want to deploy some JSP scripts on the Server. I'm using Apache Tomcat. If I put my script, called `request.jsp`, inside `WebContent` folder all it's correct. To access it, the URL were: `http://localhost:8080/MyService/resquest.jsp`. But the problem is that I want to change the URL, for example, I want the URL will be: `http://localhost:8080/MyService/rest/request.jsp`. So, to do that, I thought that it only was necessary to create the folder rest inside `WebContent` and then put the script inside this subfolder. But I'm wrong because it doesn't run and the server return to me an 404 http error, so the URL cannot be found.

What is the way to do this? Any comment is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You thought in the right direction. The default servlet should handle those requests from the web root folder. But your assumptions to use a folder name was wrong, because another servlet or filter that is served first and mapped to that folder treated it wrong. You can just use another name if you satisfied with the way are you doing.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That was exactly the problem. I had another servlet with the same name. Now i change it and Tomcat serves me the jsp pages without problems.